# stored procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

MY TASK IS - Write a stored procedure that receives as input both a string representing a category name and a real number representing the number
of calories per gram. Your procedure needs to display the filling name
and its number of calories for all fillings belonging to the category in
question whose number of calories (per gram) is upper bounded by
(≤) the entered real number. The result needs to be sorted according
to the number of calories, the smallest first.

So far I did

```
create or replace PROCEDURE CATEGORY_NAME 
(
  p_CATEGORYNAME IN VARCHAR2
, CALORIES IN NUMBER 
, p_FILLIINGNAME OUT filling.name%TYPE
, NUMBER_OF_CALORIES OUT NUMBER 
)AS
p_categoryID category.categoryid%TYPE;
BEGIN
    SELECT categoryid INTO p_categoryID FROM category where category.name = p_CATEGORYNAME;
    select filling.name, filling.gramcalories INTO p_FILLIINGNAME, NUMBER_OF_CALORIES from filling where categoryid = p_categoryID and gramcalories <= CALORIES;
    --ORDER BY filling.gramcalories ASC;
  --SELECT NAME INTO FILLIINGNAME FROM CATEGORY WHERE category.name=CATEGORYNAME;
  --SELECT gramcalories INTO NUMBER_OF_CALORIES FROM FILLING WHERE GRAMCALORIES=number_of_calories;

END CATEGORY_NAME;
```

But when I try to execute in command prompt it doesn't work at all. Can anyone please help me

Comment: The code looks like Oracle, not MySQL. Refine...